# How to introduce a parameter to SQL server using MS Access as a front-end UI?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, parameterized

I am using MS Access as a front-end and using an ODBC SQL Server Driver for data.

How is that I can parameterize my query using a field from an MS Access form?

Here is my current working query (however, I need DALLAS to be a parameter I can pass from a MS Access form):

```
Select LPID,Name_Long, MR_Markets from baf_center
Where  Guild_Markets = 'DALLAS';
```

Should this be handled in VBA instead?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that an actual Access query, or a SQL String that you are executing with a command object?  My understanding is that Access queries are already sanitized internally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have field in a form and you want to use that in the where clause of a query. If so, you could reference the form field like so in the criteria of the query designer:

```
[Forms]![Your Form]![Your Form Field]
```

Let me know if I'm off-base about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using linked tables to a SQL Server database.  If so, it is an actual ODBC query.

You might be able to reference [Forms]![Your Form]![Your Form Field] in the criteria window entry under the Guild_Markets column.  However, you have to do something with the results?

You can also execute the query via VBA.

**I guess the main question is what are you trying to do?**